# Simple RC circuit connected to Transformer

Tags: capacitor, resistors, transformer, efficiency

I am trying to understand about RC circuits and am having confusion understanding power out of the secondary on an ignition coil with a simple RC circuit as load. The output of the secondary coil is pulses in the form of a sinc wave.

I initially have a setup as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM8bpO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltmeter is actually an oscilloscope probe connected to an isolated channel on an oscilloscope.

I measure the voltage drop across the 1000 ohm resistor and then calculate the current and power. The output power is approx. 0.05W, the input power is run from a power supply unit and shows me the power, 2.3W. This gives a transformer efficiency of approx. 2%.

I then add a small 80pF capacitor in series as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWX78h.png)</sup>

As before I measure the voltage drop across the 1000 ohm resistor, then calculate the current and power. The output power from the transformer has now increased by approx. 1.2W **BUT** the input from the PSU has decreased to 1.5W. This gives a transformer efficiency of 80%.

A few questions that I am not sure about:

1. Can a simple small capacitor actually increase the efficiency of the ignition coil by that much?
2. If so how? I partially understand about resonance and this contributing to the magnetising current, but can such a small capacitor actually increase the efficiency and the power draw of the ignition coil by that much?
3. If not, where am I going wrong in my understanding, measurements or calculations, or could there be something else drawing more power than the small capacitor?

The overview of the coil is here:
https://www.summitracing.com/parts/msd-8225

Comment: um, a transformer with an efficiency of 2% ? Are you **Sure** with a capital S?  What is your AC frequency, and what's your transformer?  Are you possibly loading an instrumentation transformer??

Comment: What is your transformer rating? If it's a kW rating or more then that would make sense as you are not loading it. Please [edit] to give the ratings of your transformer and, if possible, a link to the datasheet. How are you measuring the input power?

Comment: The input power is measured by reading the voltage and current off the power supply unit.

Comment: Right, so it's an ignition coil. See the datasheet. The secondary has a resistance of 8.9 kΩ so there's 90% of your losses accounted for already. "*The input power is measured by reading the voltage and current off the power supply unit.*" If you are simply multiplying volts by amps then you have forgotten to account for power-factor. The volts and amps won't be in phase for an inductive load such as the ignition coil.

Comment: OK. So how does adding the capacitor increase the power output of the coil and reduce the input power?

Comment: Exactly what is this 'power supply'? What frequency and voltage is it producing?